# How to use --extend.query-path paramether of postgres-exporter in helm chart?

Tags: postgresql, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

We have `metrics.yaml` file that we need to pass as the paramether to the postgres-exporter. How to add it and make it used in the chart like this: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-postgres-exporter/Chart.yaml ?

It is possible to set up it in values.yaml and if possible, how to do this?

I have set up according to the helm chart example:

```
customMetrics:
  pg_database:
    query: "SELECT d.datname AS name, CASE WHEN pg_catalog.has_database_privilege(d.datname, 'CONNECT') THEN pg_catalog.pg_database_size(d.datname) ELSE 0 END AS size_bytes FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d where datname not in ('template0', 'template1', 'postgres')"
    metrics:
     - name:
         usage: "LABEL"
         description: "Name of the database"
     - size_bytes:
         usage: "GAUGE"
         description: "Size of the database in bytes"
```

everything is deployed well, but this metric is not returned by the exporter

```
image:
    registry: docker.io
    repository: bitnami/postgres-exporter
    tag: 0.10.0-debian-10-r27
```

Logs say no problem with obtaining the metrics, no errors, exceptions:

```
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:39.850Z caller=log.go:168 level=info msg="Listening on address" address=:9187
level=info ts=2021-08-13T12:04:39.850Z caller=tls_config.go:191 msg="TLS is disabled." http2=false
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:40.973Z caller=log.go:168 level=info msg="Established new database connection" fingerprint=127.0.0.1:5432
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:40.998Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Querying PostgreSQL version" server=127.0.0.1:5432
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.007Z caller=log.go:168 level=info msg="Semantic version changed" server=127.0.0.1:5432 from=0.0.0 to=11.12.0
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.007Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Column is being forced to discard due to version incompatibility" column=flush_location
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.007Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Column is being forced to discard due to version incompatibility" column=procpid
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.007Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Column is being forced to discard due to version incompatibility" column=write_location
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.007Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Column is being forced to discard due to version incompatibility" column=pg_xlog_location_diff
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.007Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Column is being forced to discard due to version incompatibility" column=sent_location
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.007Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Column is being forced to discard due to version incompatibility" column=replay_location
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.007Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Querying pg_setting view" server=127.0.0.1:5432
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.022Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Querying namespace" namespace=pg_locks
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.040Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Querying namespace" namespace=pg_stat_replication
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.050Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Querying namespace" namespace=pg_replication_slots
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.052Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Querying namespace" namespace=pg_stat_archiver
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.067Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Querying namespace" namespace=pg_stat_activity
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.072Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Querying namespace" namespace=pg_stat_bgwriter
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.073Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Querying namespace" namespace=pg_stat_database
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:41.074Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Querying namespace" namespace=pg_stat_database_conflicts
ts=2021-08-13T12:04:49.847Z caller=log.go:168 level=debug msg="Querying PostgreSQL version" server=127.0.0.1:5432
```

in the logs I don't see pg_database query otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was in extra space before `customMetrics:` when it was uncommented. It should be at the same level as `image` in

```
  image:
    registry: docker.io
    repository: bitnami/postgres-exporter
    tag: 0.10.0-debian-10-r27
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

The problem was that the wrong placement was correctly validated too.